# Mail Acknowledgement to admin in magento 2

Tags: php, email, frontend, magento2.2

I have created the **frontend** form as **a popup window** which **contains** name and email etc.... while **clicking submit** the **contents** automatically set as a **mail content** and want to **send** a that to a **custome**r. In **admin side** I need to receive the acknowledgement message. please provide me a solution

Comment: do you mean notification or admin email?

Comment: I need success message to admin

Comment: success msg on admin side?